# Python, keeps looping where it is supposed to be proceeded (used while and if-statement)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
def buyingApp():
    appDownPick=1
    while (appDownPick !=0):
        appDownPick = int(input("\nWhich application do you want to download?\nPlease specify the index of the application\nIf you don't want to download, please enter 0.: "))
        if (appDownPick == 1):
            appDownCon = input("You've chosen to download 'PUBG Mobile'. The price of the application is US$5. Do you want to download this application? (Y/N): ")
            if (appDownCon == Y):
                if (getBalanceasTotal (ledge)<0): #When balance is not enough, it would not work.
                    print ("Insufficient funds")
                    print ("Please restart and try again")
                    break
                elif (getBalanceasTotal(ledge)>0): #When balance is enough to purchase, it would download and saved in the document.
                spendBalance (0,5.0,"You have downloaded PUBG Mobile for US$5.")
                    print ("You have downloaded PUBG Mobile.")
                    break
            elif (appDownCon == N):
                break
```

I am working on this code, which is asking the user to choose whether they are going to download the app or not at the end and should run.

However, when my code is in run, it just keep asking appDownPick and appDownCon, when it is supposed to proceed to purchasing related code.

Which part should I fix in order for this code to run?

+) This is run by the code below

```
option = 1 #Declare option as 1 so that while loop can work, and until the user puts 0, this, option command will keep looping.
while (option!=0):
    option = int(input("Options:\n1. Search by Category\n2. Search by Name (This option requires to type the exact name of the application)\n3. Download the application\nPlease enter 0 to quit App Store."))
    if (option == 1):
        categorize()
    elif (option == 2):
        search()
    elif (option == 3):
        buyingApp()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: When I run this (after fixing your indentation errors), I don't see anything like the behavior you report. What I see is a `NameError` because there's no such variable as `Y`.

Comment: … and if I fix that problem, and type `N`, the `break` works just fine. Of course if I type `n`, it doesn't. Maybe that's the problem you're seeing? If so, the problem is that `'N'` and `'n`' aren't the same string; you probably want `appDownCon = input(…).upper()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need use quotes (' or ") in constants strings. So, change:

```
appDownCon == Y
appDownCon == N
```

to:

```
appDownCon == 'Y'
appDownCon == 'N'
```

Comment: That's true, but it has nothing to do with the error the OP is asking about.